# Is there a mistake in this problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:
Suppose A is a set, and for every family of sets F, if ∪F = A then
A ∈ F. Prove that A has exactly one element.

However, i can come up with a counterexample. Suppose A = {1,2} and A ∈ F. Then ∪F = {1,2} = A.
Do you think the author made a mistake or am i the wrong one here ?

Comment: For the family of sets $F=\{F_1,F_2\}$ where $F_1=\{1\}$ and $F_2=\{2\}$, we have $\cup F=\{1,2\}$ but $A\not\in F$.

Comment: I think the question maybe should have been. Prove that the above statement is true when A has exactly one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the contradiction is in your example. However, if we choose $F=\{\{x\}\,\,|\,\,x\in A\}$, then $\bigcup F = A$, thus $A\in F$, thus $|A| = \{x\}$ for some $x$, thus $|A|=1$.

Comment: Well A has two elements. So does ∪F in that case. So A doesnt have exactly one element

Comment: @АлександърГьорев How, or why, do you deduce $\;A\;$ has *two* elements?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Marc said he is not sure what my contradiction is. I state that in the case of ∪F = {1,2} it follows that A = {1,2} which has two elements.

Comment: This example is very accurate and correct, imo: **any** set is the (pairwise disjoint, by the way) union of its singletons. In this case, our $\;A\;$ is expressed by such union, **so the condition** tells us $\;A\;$ is one of these singletons! And thus $\;A\;$ has only one element. Q.E.D. Very nice. +1

Comment: @АлександърГьорев In this problem, each set $A$ generates a family of sets $G$, which consists of all $F$ such that $\cup F = A$. The assumption is that if $H \in G$ then $A \in H$. For $A=\{ 1,2 \}$, $G$ contains $\{ \{ 1 \},\{ 2 \} \}$, which does not contain $A$. So the set $\{ 1,2 \}$ does not satisfy the hypotheses of the problem.

Comment: @Ian Rather, the family of sets $\;F=\{\{1\},\,\{2\}\}\;\;$ and the set $\;A=\{1,2\}\;$ don't fulfill the question's condition.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I can see it now.

Comment: @Timbuc No, I said what I meant. $A=\{ 1,2 \}$ fails to satisfy the *universal* condition "for every family of sets $F$, ..." The counterexample is $F$, but $A$ itself fails to satisfy the universal condition. Your correction would be like saying that $\varepsilon=1/2$ and the Heaviside function fail to satisfy the condition of continuity of a function.

Comment: @Ian Do you mean *your* $\;A\;$ fails to fulfill the condition?

Comment: @Timbuc Yes; this is how I phrased it originally prior to your attempt at a correction. (These unfounded corrections are getting a bit irritating, by the way.)

Comment: @Ian It's a pity you misunderstood the question and posted a wrong answer, and then made things even more confusing with you "explanations". Don't worry, I won't attempt to correct your stuff any more.

Comment: @Timbuc I did not misunderstand the question, you are correcting grammar at best!

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that, for *every* $F$ with $\cup F=A$, $A \in F$. For illustration, fix $A=\{ 1,2 \}$ for this paragraph. You are correct that if $F=\{ \{ 1,2 \} \}$, then $\cup F=A$ and $A \in F$. But if $F=\{ \{ 1 \},\{ 2 \} \}$ then $\cup F=A$ and $A \not \in F$. That is, this $F$ shows that the hypothesis of the problem does not hold for $A=\{ 1,2 \}$.

With this counterexample in mind, you can come up with a proof for the original statement: if $F$ is the set of all singleton subsets of $A$, then $\cup F=A$. Now if $A \in F$ then $A$ is a singleton subset of itself, that is, $A$ has one element.

A different proof: if $F$ is the set of all singleton subsets of $A$, then $F=A$. If $A$ has more than one element, then $A$ cannot be a member of $F$ (since every member of $F$ is a singleton). Now the result follows by contraposition.

Comment: But the problem states that if ∪F = A then A ∈ F. I dont think this is normal for sets in general, i think that this property is specific for this problem. Assume that A = {1,2} and ∪F = {1,2}. By the description of the problem doesnt this mean A∈F ?

Comment: @АлександърГьорев The assumption is that no matter what family $F$ you pick, if the union of all the members of $F$ is $A$, then $A$ is itself a member of $F$. In the case $A=\{ 1,2 \}$, this property does not hold, because with $F=\{ \{ 1 \},\{ 2 \} \}$, $\cup F = A$ but $A \not \in F$. Yes, $F=\{ \{ 1,2 \} \}$ has the property as well, but this is irrelevant. One only needs one counterexample to disprove a universal statement.

Comment: I agree with that. What i am trying to say is that this is an explicit and specific condition for this problem only.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев I don't understand what you mean. Sure, it is not always the case that if $\cup F = A$ then $A \in F$.

Comment: We know that if ∪F = A then A ∈ F is true. How can it be possible for ∪F = A and A ∉ F if this is what the problem states.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев In *general* it is not true that if $\cup F = A$ then $A \in F$. I have already presented a counterexample in the form of $A=\{ 1,2 \}$ and $F=\{ \{ 1 \},\{ 2 \} \}$. Perhaps you are confused about notation? $\cup F$ means $\bigcup_{f \in F} f$. For instance $\cup \{ \{ 1 \},\{ 2 \} \}=\{ 1 \} \cup \{ 2 \}=\{ 1,2 \}$.

Comment: @Ian, I think you got it wrong: the assumption is: if $\;\cup F=A\implies A\in F\;$ . Under **this** assumption one must prove, or disprove, that $\;A\;$ is a singleton.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев And I think it is right, indeed...and the answer by Marc proves this, imo.

Comment: I am very confused as to what the problem is. The problem adopts a hypothesis, which as it turns out doesn't hold for all sets $A$ but only for some sets $A$. Why does it matter that this hypothesis fails for some sets $A$?

Comment: Ian, the assumption is: $\;A\;$ is a set such that if it is the union of some sets then it is one of *those sets*. The question now is: under this condition, is it true that $\;A\;$ has only one element? Marc's answer is correct, imo.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Sorry, when I said "problem" I meant "difficulty". I understand the problem statement entirely, and verbally expressed a proof identical to Marc's in my own answer. I'm confused by АлександърГьорев's concern "how can it be possible for ...?"

Comment: Ian, your "counterexample" is **not** an actual counterexample: in this case it is not true that $\;\cup F=A\implies A\in F\; $ ! Thus, it is impossible to continue as the  problem's condition on $\;A\;$ isn't fulfilled.

Comment: @Timbuc First of all, $F=\{ \{ 1 \},\{ 2 \} \}$, not $A=\{ 1,2 \}$, is the counterexample. It is not a counterexample to the statement "for every $A$ such that ...". It is a counterexample to the statement "for $A=\{ 1,2 \}$ and every $F$ such that ..." Note that this is how I worded it in my answer: $F$ supplies the counterexample for this particular $A$. You are either getting confused about order of quantifiers or essentially making a grammatical nitpick or both.

Comment: @Timbuc To put it another way, I am proving the original statement by contraposition: if $A$ is a set with more than one element, then there exists $F$ such that $\cup F = A$ and $A \not \in F$.